# Finding a travel partner

Tags: online-resources, international-travel, safety

I love to travel, and I'd like to travel with either a small group or at least with another person. The problem is, I can't find a partner for travel every time my time slot opens up. Once I met this nice person (it was a foreigner) during one of my journeys I did alone, and I got the chance to meet this new person and we shared a ride for the final part of my ride. We became friends since.

Is there any place (website or community or similar) where people are openly looking for travel partners/mates, and a person can apply and post about his/her idea for travel, then communicate with interested others?

It could be about any place, something like, I'm in UK and I've plans to visit Surrey. Someone else from another country or in the same country as me is planing to do the same. So we can post it openly and if interested, then we can make arrangements to travel along.

Is there any service, community out there for this?

Answer (score 3):

In Poland there are many groups on Facebook, like [Looking for a traveler](https://www.facebook.com/groups/podroznikposzukiwany/), with 60k+ members. The rule is to post where and when you want to go, write some short info about yourself and your idea of the trip and that's it pretty much. There should be similar ones in other countries, I used that one several times and every time I found someone.

And maybe it's not specifically what you're looking for, but I used Couchsurfing for that purpose:

- In the menu on the top you can choose **Find Travelers** and you'll see a list of people going to specified city in following months. Of course some of them are looking for accommodation specifically, but it doesn't hurt to send them a message and ask if they want to hang out together
- Many places have groups, like this one called [Surrey Couchsurfers](https://www.couchsurfing.com/groups/surrey-couchsurfers), I'm not sure about other countries but in Brazil I saw people looking for other travelers to spend time / travel together.

Comment: Hi @Cuba, appreciate the answer.. :)  You've mentioned facebook groups. tried one or two based on quick search. had no luck though. I'll look into the things you've suggested. thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

A good way for me was [couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/dashboard).

Either in the hangouts as you arrived or search for other travellers in that location.

Everywhere I went till now i managed to find locals/other travelers to hang around and/or discover the countries.

You can find other travelers in the same location and time pattern [here](https://www.couchsurfing.com/members/travelers?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_type=traveler&placeid=ChIJW6c_TQPchVQR4JjVq5hIi9I&search_query=Surrey%2C%20BC%2C%20Canada).